# Python gives 'TypeError: 'PyQt6.sip.wrappertype' object is not iterable' error when running simple PyQt6 script

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have python newly installed, and am trying to create a simple window using sample code from the internet:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

````
```
`# Only needed for access to command line arguments
import sys

# You need one (and only one) QApplication instance per application.
# Pass in sys.argv to allow command line arguments for your app.
# If you know you won't use command line arguments QApplication([]) works too.
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create a Qt widget, which will be our window.
window = QWidget()
window.show()  # IMPORTANT!!!!! Windows are hidden by default.

# Start the event loop.
app.exec()`
```
````

But the code runs with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\XXXX\Documents\My Documents\Projects\Python\helloworld.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
TypeError: 'PyQt6.sip.wrappertype' object is not iterable
```

I can find no record of this problem anywhere else.

I ran the code after a restart, and ran the more complicated code which utilizes essentially the same command as this one. I separated the calls such that PyQt6 only receives one 'import' call at a time, but the error does not change.
I've also looked online for any solutions others have had with no success. My next step is to try installing python on a totally separate computer - colleagues run this code with absolutely no issue, so it's definitely something wrong with my install or setup.

Comment: Please ensure that you are properly pasting and displaying code (see the [formatting guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)). Also, ensure that you don't have a folder or script named "PyQt6" in that same directory.

Answer (score 0):

For the record of anyone facing this problem, my issue was that I was running version 3.10.0a6, which for whatever reason caused this nebulous error. I uninstalled all versions of python from my computer, then reinstalled the latest (at the moment 3.11.5), and the issue no longer presents.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).